# how do i prevent logged in users from accessing the login page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

i have been trying to prevent user that are logged in not to go back to the login page.
please i need your help.
i've tried different method, but yet to no avail. i will be much grateful if anyone can help me. Thanks.

**here is my php code for login**

```
<?php 
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
    
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
       if(empty($_POST['student']) || empty($_POST['pass']))
       {
            $_SESSION['message'] = " student id and password is required";
       }
       else
       {
           $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
           $student = $_POST['student'];
            $query= "select studentid, password, status from student_register where studentid='$student' and password='$password'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($row)
            {
                $_SESSION['user']=$_POST['student'];
                $_SESSION['stat'] = $row['status'];
                $_SESSION['message'] =" Login successfully";
                header("refresh:5;url= Welcome.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] =" Student id or password is incorrect";
            }
       }
    }
    else
    {
        
    }

?>
```

Comment: On any page (except the login page itself) just check if `empty($_SESSION['user'])`, and if true, redirect.

Comment: **Never store `md5()` passwords!** Please use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so _changes_ the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Comment: and on login page check the opposite: if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {//redirect to homepage}. And fix sql injection issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a small code into you `login.php` file to check the user already login or not.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{
  header("LOCATION: Welcome.php");
}
```

If session is already set, redirect it back to `welcome.php`.

Use this code for those pages which require login to access the page.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{
  header("LOCATION: login.php");
}
```